# solving basic complex equations

Tags: complex-numbers

if I am given a complex equation like this:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x+iy+2+3i}{2x+2iy-3}=i+2
\end{equation}

How do I go about solving this equation? Is it necessary to get an expression in the form z=x+iy on the left hand side or is there a shortcut?

Comment: In this case at least, it seems it would be easier to let $z=x+iy$ as you stated and work from there to solve for $z$. (Note that $2x+2iy = 2(x+iy)=2z$.) I'm not going to guarantee it works but it seems as good a place as any to start at.

Comment: By "solve", you may be required to find x, y. You should think of terms z=x+iy to do this. First step is to multiply by $2x+2iy-3) both sides assuming this is not zero, get an equation with real and imaginary parts, equate each and solve for x,y. If you are stuck tell us.

Comment: Is it basic or is it complex ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x+iy+2+3i}{2x+2iy-3}=i+2$$
we will try what others suggested:
$z=x+iy$
$$\frac{z+2+3i}{2z-3}=\frac{(2z-3)(i+2)}{2z-3}$$
$$z+2+3i=(2z-3)(i+2)$$
$$z+2+3i=2zi+4z-3i-6$$
$$3z+2zi-8-6i=0$$
$$3z+2zi=8+6i$$
$$3(x+iy)+2(-y+ix)=8+6i$$
so we can obtain simultaneous equations by taking $\Re$ and $\Im$ parts:
$$3x-2y=8$$
$$2x+3y=6$$
now solve

Answer (score 0):

Solving the equation means that you must provide *explicit* values for the unknowns, $x$ and $y$.

Using complex number, you can write

$$\frac{z+2+3i}{2z-3}=2+i$$ and solve for $z$ by symbolic manipulation.

This yields

$$(2(2+i)-1)z=2+3i+3(2+i),$$ then

$$z=\frac{2+3i+3(2+i)}{2(2+i)-1}.$$

Now you do have to extract the real and imaginary parts, as $x,y$ are requested.